# Rive animation freezes and reload web page on iOS

Tags: ios, rive

Rive animation freezes and reload web page on iOS when running after a few minutes (Rive Web - Nuxt3)

Get some solutions, ideas from other experience developers about how to implement it on right ways on web browsers for nuxt or vue framework